Docker Swarm + Traefik + Nginx (3 VMs)
I have 3 vms (main, node-1, node-2), the public IP of main server is 1.1.1.1
I initiated docker swarm on main server (leader)
and "JOIN" node-1 and node-2
I would like to try the load balancing between the 3 servers and for this:

Create service Traefik on main server (leader)

sudo docker service create \
  --name traefik \
  --constraint=node.role==manager \
  --publish 80:80 \
  --publish 8080:8080 \
  --network web \
  --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock \
  traefik:v2.5 \
  --entrypoints.web.address=:80 \
  --providers.docker \
  --api.insecure=true

=> http://1.1.1.1:8080 is OK as expected (Traefik dashboard)

Create service (on main server) Nginx with replicas = 3 to deploy on each server one Nginx service

 docker service create \
  --name my-nginx \
  --replicas 3 \
  --network web \
  --config source=my_nginx_conf,target=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  --label "traefik.enable=true" \
  --label "traefik.http.routers.my-nginx.rule=Host(`1.1.1.1`)" \
  --label "traefik.http.services.my-nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=80" \
  nginx


=> I can check on each server (with docker ps) that a Nginx is UP
My issue: When i go on http://1.1.1.1, I receive an error 404.
It seems that the labels are not applied correctly. If I go on Traefik dashboard, I find
a router rule (i expected read http://1.1.1.1)
Host('traefik-1-yxc8jw0341hivva1kik8568lt')

If I check the labels:
docker service inspect my-nginx --format '{{json .Spec.TaskTemplate.ContainerSpec.Labels}}' | jq .

=> null

But i can read in detail below:
sudo docker service inspect my-nginx --format '{{json .Spec.Labels}}' | jq .
{
  "traefik.enable": "true",
  "traefik.http.routers.my-nginx.rule": "Host(1.1.1.1)",
  "traefik.http.services.my-nginx.loadbalancer.server.port": "80"
}

Does anybody know a constraint about label scope? Or the root of the issue?
Thanks

You have 3 VMs (virtual machines) on 1 server and want to use each as Docker Swarm node, install Docker Swarm inside each VM?
You don't set how many Traefik instances you want (replicas or global). By using --publish 80:80 --publish 8080:8080 you create an ingress network for those ports, so every node will listen on the ports and forward to existing Traefik services, potentially on another node.
Enable and check Traefik debug log and access log. Check Traefik dashboard on http://:8080/dashboard/`.
Note: Please do not use 2 year old Traefik v2.5 but update to v2.11 or v3.1.

thanks, in fact i have 3 vms on 3 distincts servers. I will try with replicas on traefik.
